# JSON.NET - Recognizing a nested array

Tags: c#, json.net

I have this code for getting values out of a json string.

```
        var json = @"[{""property"":""Status"",""value"":""val""}]";

        var jArray = JArray.Parse(json);

        foreach (JToken jToken in jArray)
        {
            var property = jToken.Value<string>("property");
            var value = jToken.Value<string>("value");             
        }
```

This works perfect for the provided input. But in some situations the value property may contain an array.

```
        var json = @"[{""property"":""Status"",""value"":[1,2]}]";
```

I'd like to check somehow if the value contains a simple value or an array. If the value is an array then bind it to a collection.

Is this possible using JSON.net ?

Comment: This is a different tack on it, but I use a variation of the code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object. If you like that, I'll post my version of the code (it fixes some bugs, including, I believe, one that involved either contained arrays or contained objects. Can't remember which.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dynamic value = jToken["value"];
if (value is JArray)
    // do something
```

(you could use `object` instead of `dynamic` in my example, but `dynamic` might be easier to work with later)

Comment: FYI, you can also use `if (value.Type == JTokenType.Array)`.